# Booting monolithic kernel: cannot find root fs by UUID

Tags: 13.10, kernel, lvm

I have built a monolithic kernel with the grsecurity patch, since I don't need many modules for the system and I need to optimize space. When trying to boot the new kernel, it yields a busybox shell, claiming the root filesystem could not be found by its UUID:

```
 /dev/disk/by-uuid/7b30b4c6-...
```

The chipset is supported by the kernel (Supermicro server):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C202 Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
04:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)
```

I confirmed that the UUID exists properly, via blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="0a46c81f-..." TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda5: UUID="vpQHTm-..." TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/blah--vg-root: UUID="7b30b4c6-..." TYPE="ext4"
```

Therefore the LVM volume group and the correct volume with the requested UUID are present. I can boot the normal modular kernel just fine.

What is wrong?

edit:

The LVM config is fine, still no devmapper nodes?:

```
(initramfs) lvm vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               xxx-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  19
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                6
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               465.52 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119173
  Alloc PE / Size       119173 / 465.52 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               xxx

(initramfs) lvm lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xxx-vg/root' [37.25 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xxx-vg/tmp' [4.66 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xxx-vg/var' [18.62 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xxx-vg/blah' [186.26 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xxx-vg/swap' [3.72 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xxx-vg/home' [215.00 GiB] inherit
(initramfs) ls /dev/mapper/
control
(initramfs) reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

The IPC hardening feature of grsecurity breaks semaphores for lvm... that was the culprit. Deactivating it fixes this problem.